# Undefined variable with get method chek login

Tags: php, variables, get, undefined

i have php file include this line:

> $uid = $_GET['uid'];

but if I open this page Directly i have this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: uid in D:\xampp\htdocs\ask\index.php on
>   line 6

sometimes i need direct access and sometimes not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['uid']))
{
$id=$_GET['uid'];
}
else
{
$id='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if(isset($_GET['uid'])
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` takes the values from the URL parameter. And you are opening it directly that's why it is not getting **uid** index from URL parameter and giving this error.

To omit this error you need to do this:

```
$uid = (isset($_REQUEST['uid'])) ?  $_REQUEST['uid'] : '';
```

Use the `$_REQUEST` because it takes the values from get and post both commonly, this will be good practice to you.

If you are hitting the URL directly then you need to give the parameter like this:

> your_url?uid=xxx //any value as you want can give

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($_GET['uid']!=""){
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
}
```